# Am I using SSL Sockets incorrectly?

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on android app that is p2p, and I started using SSLSockets to secure the connection, everything works, and by that I mean I get a connection (not handshake error) established, I receive data, and I am able to send data, but I feel like its only working due to a fluke in the code. I am only using one keystore, and its the same one on my client, and server application.

Server:

```
String[] enabledCipherSuites = { "SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5" };
        //serverSkt = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(getAssets().open("serverkeystore"), "mypassword".toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keyStore,"mypassword".toCharArray());
        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslcontext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketF = sslcontext.getServerSocketFactory();
        sslServerSkt = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketF.createServerSocket(PORT);
        sslServerSkt.setEnabledCipherSuites(enabledCipherSuites);
```

Client:

```
String[] enabledCipherSuites = { "SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5" };
           AssetManager aM = getAssets();
           InputStream  kSIS = aM.open("serverkeystore");
           KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
           keyStore.load(kSIS, "mypassword".toCharArray());

           TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
           tmf.init(keyStore);

           SSLContext sslC = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
           sslC.init(null,tmf.getTrustManagers(),null);

           SSLSocketFactory sslSF = sslC.getSocketFactory();
           s1 = (SSLSocket) sslSF.createSocket(IP,PORT);
           s1.setEnabledCipherSuites(enabledCipherSuites);
           s1.startHandshake();
```

I read about having two keystores (or certificates?) on the server side (no mentioned of the client side) one would be called truststore (what do they mean by that?) and one called client, like I said earlier, I only made one, and put the same one on each app, is that wrong to do? I used portecle to make the bks keystore file.

I am also conerned about this line here

```
kmf.init(keyStore,"mypassword".toCharArray());
```

it seems bad practice to hard code a password. Is there a way around this? Maybe encrypting the string, and have the app decrypt it when it needs the keystore?

I went and googled ssl sockets with android, but most of the results returned for HTTPS, which is not what I need.

Comment: No you aren't. You shouldn't mess around with the enabled cipher suites, and you should *certainly* never enable the anonymous ones unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Comment: If I use a default one with Android would that be better? Also, if I don't use ciphersuites, should I just take it out of my code on server, and client side? Also you are saying (besides the cipher suite) that my code is ok then?